# Can I access w3c style logs when using firebase hosting

Tags: logging, w3c, firebase-hosting

I am using firebase hosting and would like access to w3c style internet access logs for the traffic going to my domain. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update 2020-08-12** Firebase Hosting now let's you [view, search, and filter your site's web request logs with Cloud Logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/web-request-logs-and-metrics).

<strike>No.</strike>

*Disclosure: I work for Firebase.*

Firebase's Hosting is most often used for single-page applications that are built on top of Firebase's realtime database. In such applications, the number of times a static resource is retrieved is not a good indicator of the application's usage. Instead of that, most developers rely on the Firebase dashboard that shows the database usage over time, including the number of concurrent connections, data transfer and data storage.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I am not trying to see the applications usage but was wanting to have a closer look at referrer traffic, Source IPs, etc. We use GA already to view some of the stats but it is not granular enough for my current requirements.

Comment: Me too +1, Is there any kind of solutions?

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is a few years old but what the hell... it's saturday. It looks like the preferred pattern would be to move all your API calls and anything else that's error prone into a Firebase function and add a handler there. You can view this log from your Firebase console...