# Where can I see the log of urls which triggered a Cloud Function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

One of my functions sometimes returns an error status when invoked with a HTTP trigger. I see the function name and the error code in the Firebase function logs, but not the actual request which resulted in an error.

The function does dynamic url rewrites for a Firebase Hosting site, so it is invoked by Firebase hosting when the static rules don't match the incoming url.

Where can I see the log of the urls which triggered this rewrite function? I don't see it in the Logs Viewer (the function invocation time is there, just not the url).

Where else the url which actually invoked the function can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such log exists (that is accessible to the developer).  [Firebase Hosting doesn't provide any request logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669725/can-i-access-w3c-style-logs-when-using-firebase-hosting).  You could put together something yourself by passing the original URL as a parameter to the function, the let the function log it.

You are free to [file a feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) if you like.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find it, so I caught the exception in the function and logged manually the url from there.  Firebase hosting should log the url at least in case of an error in a http triggered function to help finding bugs in functions.